# Error al levantar proyecto Angular 9

Tags: nodejs, angular

Tengo un proyecto en angular 9 al cual le doy npm install y ng serve o npm start y obtengo lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los logs:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El proyecto lo iniciaste con la versión 9 de angular o lo actualizaste??

Comment: Lo actualizo un colega

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrando e instalando devuelta el node_modules me funciono, dejo el link por cualquier
cosa.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30436256/9137427

Answer (score 0):

*Bueno yo actualicé un proyecto también y se me presentó errores también con varias librerías, por unas modificaciones que hicieron en angular 9. prueba agregar en tu archivo **tsconfig.app.json** la siguiente linea:*

[image: tsconfig.app.json]

*En la imagen se puede observar un **compilerOptions**, comparalo con el que tienes, si mal no recuerdo debes agregar el **types**.*

*Luego de realizar este proceso, elimina el node modules y ejecutas de nuevo npm install.*

*Espero te sirva*

Comment: Ahi no me tira mas los errores que mostre antes pero ahora me informa sobre el package.json:

Cannot find module 'D:\ProfessionalApp\FrontendApp\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

Comment: Si vas a tu node_modules, ¿encuentras la carpeta schema-utils? de ser así, ve a la carpeta dist y mira si está el index.js

Comment: No tenia la carpeta dist, pero encontre en otro post que borran la carpeta y lo instalan devuelta. Asi que ahi dejo la solucion en otra respuesta. Igual, gracias por responder!

Comment: @FrancoRolando por eso te preguntaba, por lo general cuando se presentan ese tipo de errores lo recomendable es que borres tu node modules, luego ejecutes el npm intall de nuevo.